# Android ScrollView gets cut off at the bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to programmatically add form fields picked from an HTML file to a LinearLayout. I have a next button at the bottom but it keeps getting cut off in the display. I tried it on a tablet and it still doesnt show up.

Here's a screenshot of the app:
[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the elements are getting rendered but the last one runs off the screen for some reason.

Fragment's XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".dataInput.PropertyInfoFragment"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_property_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Calling Activity's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".dataInput.DataInputActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am calling a method `formInflator` that I made in the fragment's `onCreateView` and passing the LinearLayout from the fragment and an `Elements` object (from Jsoup library) which contains all the Elements that I want to put inside the LinearLayout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_property_info, container, false);
    nextButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButtonPressed();
        }
    });

    helpers.formInflator((LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_property_info), generator.propertyTextElements);
    return view;

}
```

Here's the method `formInflator`:

```
public void formInflator(LinearLayout parentLayout, Elements formElements) {
    TextInputLayout index = null;
    for(Element textField : formElements) {
        TextInputEditText editText = new TextInputEditText(context);
        editText.setId(View.generateViewId());
        editText.setHint(textField.id());
        editText.setText(textField.text());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

        TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context);
        textInputLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
        textInputLayout.setTag(textField.id());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textInputLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (index == null)
            index = textInputLayout;
        else
            textInputLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, index.getId());

        textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(textInputLayoutParams);
        textInputLayout.addView(editText, editTextParams);

        parentLayout.addView(textInputLayout, textInputLayoutParams);
        index = textInputLayout;
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if it's a scrollview surely you can just scroll up to see the rest of "cut-off" content? what is the intended behaviour you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @wanpanman I think I didnt word my question properly. The issue is that there's supposed to be a button after all the EditText views. However the ScrollView does not scroll all the way to the bottom. What I've shown in the screenshot is the furthest it goes.

Comment: I have a feeling its due to the action bar. I am facing the same issue.

I am using a tabbed activity, and inside the tabs I have `EditText`s. Initially, the bottom gets cut off just like OP's. But once i activate a `EditText` and the soft keyboard comes up, the action bar vanishes(this is another issue I can't seem to solve), but the `ScrollView` works perfectly, even after the keyboard is removed (action bar is still missing).

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39090963/1617737

Comment: If your **(Nested)ScrollView** is inside a **ConstraintLayout**, on your scrollview you may need to set `android:layout_height="0dp"` (along with `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf`) - as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44843684/1617737.

Answer (score 16):

Try the Nested ScrollView. It did wonders for me.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    -----
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

LinearLayout<
-----
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Exact solution of this problem for API 21 - 29.

Answer (score 13):

Change your `ScrollView` layout_height to `match_parent`.  It's the child that gets `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely helps! However it doesnt solve the problem completely. Now it scrolls to the bottom of the last `EditText` view but the `Button` still gets cut off. I tried moving the `Button` above the second `LinearLayout` and that results in the last `EditText` being cutoff again

Comment: In `formInflator`, you are trying to set `RelativeLayout` layout params for the `TextInputLayout` added to `parentLayout`.  But `parentLayout` is a `LinearLayout`, not a `RelativeLayout`, so that can't possibly be doing what you expect.

Answer (score 10):

The most close solution that I have ever found is adding a ghost view... If the ScrollView is eating part of the last element, give it a cookie.

Ex:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"/>
```

Comment: You can simply add bottom padding to the content inside your scrollview.

Comment: Nobody should use this suggestions. The scrollview will still be cutted off at the bottom even if the content is shown...

Answer (score 5):

Here's how i figured out how to do it without padding. The scrollview gets perfectly to the bottom on every screen size and orientation I have tried. Notice the height is 0dp and there is a constraint to the bottom of parent.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LLHeaders">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLVisitorList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <My dynamically generated LinearLayout horizontal rows go here>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your action bar to the activity. Android will then better recognise the view port and add the missing toolbar height on the bottom, when you scroll.

**AppCompatActivity**

```
Toolbar toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
// if needed...
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```