# Scrollview inside constraint layout does not scroll to the bottom of the parent constraint

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a form which has around 12/13 fields. I used a `Scrollview` inside a constraint layout. Below is the hierarchy of the XML layout. The problem is, it doesn't scroll to the bottom instead scrolls only to the first initial 10 views. The last 3 fields gets hidden as the view does not scroll any further.

PARENT LAYOUT

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_register"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Textview and a button -->

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Child Views (12/13 views of the fields)-->

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_height` parameter of `ScrollView` to `match_parent`.

Comment: Tried, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: set height to match parent and fillViewPort true for your scrollview,Or try nested SCrollview

Comment: which version of ConstraintLayout are you using? Could you post the full xml layout?

Comment: compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0'

Comment: could you provide the full layout ? (i.e. with the fields)

Comment: Hey did you find a solution for it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Looks to me as if you have a constraint layout inside a scrollview, not the other way around.

Answer (score 121):

This layout works in my app.
The trick is to set these two attributes in ScrollView:
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

The simplified layout from my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/title"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/title"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/title"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:hint="toilet title"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/open_hour"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/titleView"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            ...
            Other Views in ScrollView
            ...
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This works, but any reason to why 0dp works instead of wrap_content or match_parent?

Comment: In my case **`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"  `**  added to ScrollView works. great . I googled for many times until I found this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Remember that the OUTER **contraintlayout** usually should have `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. Otherwise the scrollview won't be visible with   `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: I have tried many examples both using "match_parent" and "wrap_content" neither work, use "0dp" it works

Answer (score 19):

In my case `NestedScrollView` worked instead of `ScrollView`. Following is the snippet of my working layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Some Views Here -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- Some Views That can be Scrolled Here -->

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Also add   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" in Manifest file Activity.

Answer (score 18):

You have two solutions for this problem (the same solution but in two ways to do it):

1. If you put the **Design mode** in Android Studio, select your ScrollView and open attributes tab and in the layout_height, select "**match_constraint**".
2. If you use the **Text mode** in Android Studio, use this:

   ```
   <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tb_details">
   ```

See that the ScrollView height is set to 0dp. Both of this ways resolve the same problem but these are the different ways to do it.

The ScrollView is not the root view, I have a Constraint layout wrapping the ScrollView as you.

Comment: This worked. I have a ConstraintLayout with a child ScrollView that has a child LinearLayout that I populate with rows dynamically. The key in this solution is that the height (the axis of scrolling) has to be set to 0 AND the ScrollView must be constrained on both sides of the scrolling axis (top and bottom constraints in this case. If you have a horizontally scrolling view you need to set width to 0 and set start and end constraints)

Answer (score 12):

Two Steps

1. Keep layout height for scroll view zero
   `android:layout_height="0dp"`
2. Again for scroll view
   `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: I my case both height and width needed to be 0dp, scrolling side needed to be match_parent, otherwise scroll did not worked. And of course all 4 constraints should be added to RecyclerView

Answer (score 10):

Try adding bottom constraint to scrollview (eg: `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`)
and change  android:layout_height="wrap_content" to  `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: I forgot bottom constraint to scrollview. thank you so much :D

Answer (score 7):

In my case `NestedScrollView` worked instead of `ScrollView`.

Following is the snippet of my working layout:
Please make sure that you haven't make any childview height to match parent(0 dp) inside constrianlayout also for scroll view **android:fillViewport="true**;

Ask me if any doubt Occur.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/cvLayout"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
```

Comment: In my case ScrollView was not working but NestedScrollView is working fine..

Answer (score 4):

Just Put `android:fillViewport="true"` in Parent Layout

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a tall `TextView` (height set to `wrap_content`) inside a `ScrollView` (height set to `0dp` and being constraint on the top and bottom). No suggestions worked, but I solved the problem by wrapping the `TextView` inside a `FrameLayout` (height set to `wrap_content`).

Answer (score 1):

**Never keep 0dp height of childs of ConstraintLayout if it is inside SV/NestedSV**

`wrap_content` works because in this case ScrollView knows its childens height.

Comment: THIS!!!! NEVER MAKE CONSTRAINTLAYOUT 0DP!!!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to add a LinearLayout inside my ScrollView in order to constrain it

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View....</View>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this issue. Inside ScrollView you can not use constraint Layout. 
for using constrain inside scroll u have to use Relative layout is parent of constraint Layout..

so ur sequence should be:

ScrollView ---> Relative Layout ---> Constraint Layout

Answer (score 0):

If you came here after searching "**Soft Keyboard Hides the View elements**"!
Then you just have to add a scrollView and the same layout element again.

Before

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView3"
       android:layout_width="246dp"
       android:layout_height="168dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:src="@drawable/img"/>
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

After

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                 android:layout_width="246dp"
                 android:layout_height="168dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/img"/>
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btn"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the horizontal scroll view case (parent is ConstraintLayout, immediate child is LinearLayout), I found that setting the four constraints, layout_width=0dp, and fillViewport=true was not enough. It still didn't scroll.

What did work in my case was to set the four constraints and change the element from ScrollView to HorizontalScrollView. In that case layout_width can be set to "wrap_content" and fillViewport can be omitted.
Additionally, I added a padding at the end of the immediate child of the HorizontalScrollView, to make the scrolling experience and the look better.

Answer (score 0):

I faced another issue where i had `nestedscrollview` which has `constrainlayout` which has `linearlayout`. This `linearlayout` has child get added programatically. So scroll was not working. Solved by `replacing` CL with LL with vertical orientation

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/separatr"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:background="@color/yellow_highlight"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/box96">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qansTv"
            style="@style/BodyText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/box200"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/box32"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/box200"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dofdfd fsd fdfsd sdf sdfsd fsdfsd fd sdfd fsdfsdf sdfsd df sdfd fsdfsd fsdf sdfsd dflors fdfdf."
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ansImageContainerLL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/box64"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/box64"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/qansTv" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to use 2 recyclerviews and since it didn't want to scroll all the way I found a way to set to which length of the scrollview to scroll, the length is set by changing the width of the TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.ProjectsFragment"
android:background="@color/blue">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewLength"
        android:layout_width="2000dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Change the width above"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="exampletag"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
        android:tag="exampletag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late little bit ,I was facing the same issue what I did wrapped my RecyclerView Inside Linear or Relative layout and it worked like a charm,