# (Nested)ScrollView does not scroll to bottom

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I tried many many answers, but I think my ScrollView includes much more elements.

[ScrollView doesn't scroll to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131962/scrollview-doesnt-scroll-to-the-bottom)

[Android scroll view does not scroll all the way down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909726/android-scroll-view-does-not-scroll-all-the-way-down)

Even I tried with a NestedScrollView, margin bottom, padding, even with android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on child layout, and another big linear layout that includes every element in ScrollView, but no results...

> The problem is that my ScrollView doesn't scroll to the bottom of it's
>   view. I have to say that the scrollview is below an horizontal
>   guideline that it's set at 35%, maybe could be one of the reasons to
>   this abbomination?

I'll insert a sample of XML code

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_dummy1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <!-- This is the part that's 85% of the total width.-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInside"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/anotherlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.26"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                     ....
                     ....
                     much more linear and constraints layouts that opens then closes
                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--Width 85% ends-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_dummy2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also, here's a "image"( don't laugh - not too hard :) ) of how the display would look without scrolling. If I would scroll it wouldn't reach it's bottom:

[image: ScrollView]

Answer (score 0):

Your have some errors in your xml layout. Two of the close tags for linearlayout are missing and your scrollview should be inside the guideline widget.

Comment: It ends, I just didn't put them there (updated in edit). No errors in xml.